# How to confirm one of many HttpCalloutMock has been used

Tags: apex, unit-test, httpcalloutmock

If I load multiple `HttpCalloutMock`'s when settings up a test:

```
Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, MockFactory.create());
```

And I am using a `MultiRequestMock` implementation:

```
public without sharing class MultiRequestMock implements HttpCalloutMock {

    Map<String, HttpCalloutMock> requests;

    public MultiRequestMock(Map<String, HttpCalloutMock> requests) {
        this.requests = requests;
    }

    public HTTPResponse respond(HTTPRequest req) {

        HttpCalloutMock mock = requests.get(req.getEndpoint());

        if (mock != null) {
            return mock.respond(req);
        } 

        throw new CustomException('Mock for end point not found: ' + req.getEndpoint());
    }

    public void addRequestMock(String url, HttpCalloutMock mock) {
        requests.put(url, mock);
    }
}
```

And I don't persist the results from the callout.

Is there anyway to check that each\any of the `HttpCalloutMock` have been used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Declare a variable in your mock class, and set its value in the respond method. if that variable is true at the end of your test , it means mock was used and callout was done.

```
global class CalloutMock1 implements HttpCalloutMock {

    global boolean isCalled = false;
    global HTTPResponse respond(HTTPRequest req) {
        isCalled = true;
        // Create a fake response.
        // Set response values, and 
        // return response.
    }
}
```

Test Class:

```
CalloutMock1 cm1= new CalloutMock1();
Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, cm1);

//Call your code.


System.assert(cm1.isCalled);
```

---

**Edit** :Based on your updated code:

```
public without sharing class MultiRequestMock implements HttpCalloutMock {

    public Map<String, HttpCalloutMock> requests;
    public Set<String> usedEndpoints = new Set<String>();

    public MultiRequestMock(Map<String, HttpCalloutMock> requests) {
        this.requests = requests;
    }

    public HTTPResponse respond(HTTPRequest req) {

        HttpCalloutMock mock = requests.get(req.getEndpoint());
        usedEndpoints.add(req.getEndpoint());

        if (mock != null) {
            return mock.respond(req);
        } 

        throw new CustomException('Mock for end point not found: ' + req.getEndpoint());
    }

    public void addRequestMock(String url, HttpCalloutMock mock) {
        requests.put(url, mock);
    }
}
```

Test Class :

```
MultiRequestMock  mm = new MultiRequestMock (new Map<String, HttpCalloutMock>());
mm.addRequestMock();//

//Do your callouts

//Then Assert here

System.assert(mm.usedEndpoints.contains('Your endpoint') , 'Your Endpoint not called'); //Your endpoint called
System.assert(mm.usedEndpoints.size() == mm.requests.size() , 'Not all mocks were consumed');
```

Comment: Thanks. I've updated my question to expand on my `HttpCalloutMock` implementation

Comment: Hi @Robs provided pseudo code, for the same.

Comment: Thanks again @Pranay Jaiswal - I re-discovered my question and your answer today! :-D